# Solaris 9 Fail to mkdir - no permission

Tags: files, permissions, solaris, mkdir

In solaris 9 (5.9) I fail to mkdir with user builder, the user exist in the group defined as owner for that path.

```
bash-2.05$ groups builder  
other root sys   
bash-2.05$
```

and this is the file structure:

```
 bash-2.05$ ls -la / | grep opt
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         16 Apr 14  2008 opt -> /export/home/opt
bash-2.05$
bash-2.05$ ls -la /export/home/ | grep opt
drwxr-xr-x  13 root     other        512 Jan 24 11:49 opt
bash-2.05$
```

builder belong to other group, why does it fail to mkdir in /opt ?

```
bash-2.05$ pwd
/opt
bash-2.05$ mkdir dire
mkdir: Failed to make directory "dire"; Permission denied
bash-2.05$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `other` group does not have write permissions in that directory.  Write permissions are needed to create directory entries, such as files and subdirectories.

To give the `other` group write permissions, as root do

```
chmod g+w /export/home/opt
```

Comment: you are right, I missed the GROUP permission part in list files